# Печать чека/документа

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, docx

Стоит задача вывести на печать содержимое вида, подобному тому, что приложено на скриншоте. Интересуют следующие моменты:

1. Как на PHP сформировать необходимый документ, сохранить его, а затем отправить клиенту? Какого вида документ сформировать проще всего и без заморочек будет: PDF, docx или возможно еще есть какие-то форматы?
2. Как на стороне клиента (JavaScript) показать этот документ и при возможности сразу же его отправить на печать или хотя бы просто на скачивание (чтобы в дальнейшем он смог сам его открыть и распечатать)?

[image: Чек]

Comment: Легче всего сформировать html - как обычную html страницу. Потом в браузере на js можно вызывать функцию печати - `window.print();`

Comment: Да, просто печать html страницы